# How to safely blind redirect to a url?

Tags: hyperlink, security

What is the safest format for a url in a url?

For example /login?redirect=where_you_were_before

How should it be encoded/decoded. Is whitelisting required?

Comment: Did you see the answer below? Was it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

1. The vulnerability above is called the open redirect vulnerability:
   https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Open_redirect.
   To prevent the vulnerability please manage the whitelist of domains / ips in your application.
   You application should allow the redirection only to whitelist.
2. If you started to develop your own authentication framework, you may not put the “here_you_were_before” in the URL parameter. You can store it in a HTTP session

Answer (score 0):

If you never need to redirect to an external URL, you could check to see if the redirect parameter is a local URL. If it is, redirect there, otherwise redirect to some default page.